# Python find and replace generic HOSTID w/ computer hostname

Tags: python, macos, terminal, hostname

I need "HOSTID" to resolve to the machine hostname. My goal is to take this simple command, ran manually in Terminal, and make it portable in a Python script.

```
Sudo /library.nessusagent.run.sbin.nessuscli agent link -- 
key=5e30508800865f87a8dbe8993fa75d21f9e2acc7db12165050cf48b5ccbafb84 -- 
name=HOSTID --groups=Mac_OS_Systems --Host=Cloud.tenable.com --port=443
```

The below code will get me the HOSTID, how do I point it to the right place?

```
import platform
platform.node()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import platform, subprocess

# Get the HOSTID
host_id = str(platform.node())

# Make the command string and replace HOSTID with host_id's value
command = "sudo /library.nessusagent.run.sbin.nessuscli agent link -- key=5e30508800865f87a8dbe8993fa75d21f9e2acc7db12165050cf48b5ccbafb84 -- name={0} --groups=Mac_OS_Systems --Host=Cloud.tenable.com --port=443".format(host_id)

# Run the command
execute = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# Save the output
out, err = execute.communicate()

# Print the output (assuming there is an output)
print (out)
```